# How to convert to import/export ES Modules in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could someone please explain how to convert to imports in NodeJS using following example?

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by the following method.

```
 import MongoDBStore from 'connect-mongodb-session';
 import session from 'express-session';

 const MongoStore = MongoDBStore(session);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the underlying code of `connect-mongodb-session` which you can find here [Github-connect-mogodb-session](https://github.com/mongodb-js/connect-mongodb-session/blob/master/index.js) you will see that this exports something like:
`module.exports = function(connect) {`

Which basically says, that it exports (makes available for require import) a function with a parameter named connect. 
In their docs (just above this exports) they say:

```
/**
 * Returns a constructor with the specified connect middleware's Store
 * class as its prototype
 *
 * ####Example:
 *
 *     connectMongoDBSession(require('express-session'));
 *
 * @param {Function} connect connect-compatible session middleware (e.g. Express 3, express-session)
 * @api public
 */
```

Showing to the caller what is expected as parameter to this module. Some more useful examples here: [tutorialsteacher](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)